# Java FX clash with Apache POI ClassNotFoundException

Tags: javafx, apache-poi, classnotfoundexception

I prepared some code that reads Excel/edits Word file and wanted to apply it to GUI in JavaFX.
The 'dry' code works perfectly, but when I'm trying to run the method by attaching it to JavaFX button, I'm getting error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
    at application.Controller.btnGenerate(Controller.java:111)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
```

My IDE is Eclipse and I'm using following libraries:

- xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar
- poi-4.1.2.jar
- poi-excelant-4.1.2.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar
- commons-collections4-4.4.jar
- commons-compress-1.19.jar
- commons-logging-1.2.jar
- poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar

And javafx sdk - 11.0.2.
How to fix it?

@Edit - adding example code:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("test.fxml"));
        Parent root;
        
            root = (Parent) loader.load();
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 300));
            primaryStage.getScene().getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            Controller controller = (Controller) loader.getController();
            controller.setStage(primaryStage);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Button btn;
    
    private Stage primaryStage;
    
    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
        this.primaryStage=stage;
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void btnGenerate(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Btn clicked!");
            try {
                ReadExcel readExcel = new ReadExcel();
                readExcel.readExcel();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

```
public class ReadExcel {

    public void readExcel() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        
        String path = "path/to/excel";
        
        try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(path)); Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file)) {
            DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
            XSSFSheet worksheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            int lastColumn = worksheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < lastColumn; colIndex++) {
                for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < worksheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; rowIndex++) {
                    Row row = CellUtil.getRow(rowIndex, worksheet);
                    Cell cell = CellUtil.getCell(row, colIndex);
                    String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                    System.out.println(row + " " + cellValue);
                    }
                }
            }
         catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="231.0" prefWidth="238.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="-11.0" layoutY="-13.0" prefHeight="205.0" prefWidth="220.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="btn" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="78.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnGenerate" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="68.0" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Can you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: The error tells that is lacks access to `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook` while run time. The class is in `poi-4.1.2.jar`. So your `Java FX` has no access to  `poi-4.1.2.jar` while run time. To be able to help it needs a more complete example.